# How to setup a specific accessibility traversal order for RecyclerView elements?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, accessibility, talkback

I have a RecyclerView populated with cards and all those cards contain a text1 and text2 at different places within the card. I tried providing accessibilityTraversalAfter attribute to these text1 and text2 elements in order to force TalkBack to read them in the correct order(Card1.text1 -> Card1.text2), however it resulted in this order.

Card1.text1 -> Card2.text1 -> Card2.text2 -> Card2.text2

Not a surprise since the ids for the views are the same. Is there a way to force Talkback to only apply the traversal order within an element of a RecyclerView and not the entire RecyclerView in general?

Edit: To clarify the question further and to be more specific->
Inside the RecyclerView, I have custom MaterialCardView-s(BumpCardView) as elements. This BumpCardView has a layout which contains a single icon by default(let's call it a11yIcon). However inside the RecyclerView layout we use the BumpCardView like this

```
<BumpCardView>
<ConstraintLayout>
</ConstraintLayout>
</BumpCardView>
```

so we provide a container as a child to include more children.
Inside the ConstraintLayout we have a text(let's call it a11yText).

Whenever the user is swiping among the views with Talkback I want a11yIcon to be read first and then a11yText and then move onto the remaining views inside the BumpCardView. After this Talkback should move to the following BumpCardView inside the RecyclerView.
I tried using the accessibilityTraversalAfter attribute but it results in having all the visible a11yIcon-s be read first and then all the a11yText-s which makes sense I guess but that is not what I need.

Comment: To answer this question, we need more information regarding the actual layout XML used for the items themselves.

Comment: Could you not group them and make the container screen reader friendly? See ["Groups of related content"](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/principles#content-groups)

Comment: Unfortunately the two views are not conveniently placed.

Comment: You could still mark each one as "importantForAccessibility=no" and make the contentDescription of the view a combined string. Like @EpicPandaForce suggested without seeing some form of XML it's very difficult to help you

Comment: Edited my question to be more specific.